# chart color change Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts API and I don't find in documentation how to change chart color foreground from black in white
[image]

this is the code:

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',      400],
      ['2005',      460],
      ['2006',       1120],
      ['2007',      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      curveType: 'function',
      backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options), use the following...

x-axis labels...

```
hAxis: {
  textStyle: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
}
```

y-axis labels...

```
vAxis: {
  textStyle: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
}
```

legend labels...

```
legend: {
  textStyle: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
}
```